# Is it possible to embed a keylogger into a jpg image?

Tags: jpeg, keylogger, keystrokes, put

I'm curious to know if it's possible to make a jpg file that contains a keylogger that will execute when the image is opened.

I strongly believe such thing is not possible, however I'm hearing more and more rumors of this. Any thoughts?

Comment: security.stackexchange.com duplicate: [How to inject executable, malicious code into PDF, JPEG, MP3, etc.?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/8113)

Answer (score 7):

It is possible when there is a security hole in the application which you are using to open JPG file (or any other file), unless it's fake JPEG image.

So there are few scenarios:

- running fake JPEG

  Non-experienced user downloaded file and thinks it's the image (because the icon looks like an image and OS doesn't show you extension), but it could be any executable file (`.exe`, `.vbs`, `.msi`, `.cmd`, `.bat`, etc.). So if your operating system doesn't warn you when you run fake image file, the image could be shown with keylogger installed. So always check your extension before opening suspicious files.
- opening JPEG

  Any media file (and other) could carry some injected code designed to trick specific applications. They could have some flaws in parsing some data (e.g. in EXIF). So if application is buggy, the injected data could trick the application to run some arbitrary code.

  For example: [Exploit:W32/JPG Vulnerability, Exploit:W32/JPG Vulnerability, MS04-028 exploit](https://www.f-secure.com/v-descs/ms04-028.shtml)
- loading JPEG from the server

  You could inject some programming code into JPEG, so once it's parsed by web application, it can execute any code in the given language. For example JPEG file can include special tags (`<?php`, `?>`) and when parsed by badly coded application from the webhosting company (`file_get_contents()`, `fopen()`, `readfile()`), it could erase your www account.

  Example JPEG: [`php-logo-virus.jpg`](http://web.archive.org/web/20160528062725/http://php.webtutor.pl/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/php-logo-virus.jpg)

  which has this code embedded into the file:

  > ``` ÿØÿàJFIF``ÿáfExifMM*
  >   éV@HQQQ<style>body{font-size: 0;} h1{font-size: 12px !important;}</style><h1><?php echo "<hr />THIS IMAGE COULD ERASE YOUR WWW ACCOUNT, it shows you the PHP info instead...<hr />"; phpinfo(); __halt_compiler(); ?></h1> ```

  So once you open above image, add `view-source:` before the address, so you'll see the injected PHP script. Note that the above image is just the example, and it won't do anything.

  Source: [Code injection – a simple PHP virus carried in a JPEG image](http://web.archive.org/web/20170106234834/http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/13/php-code-injection-a-simple-virus-written-in-php-and-carried-in-a-jpeg-image/)
- loading JPEG file which isn't JPEG file

  When you see the link such as: `http://www.example.com/foo.jpeg`, you think it's an image, but it doesn't have to. It all depends on its MIME type and by loading it, you actually can load the script (such as Javascript), and on vulnerable/old browser, could install a keylogger. On the other hand, your browser doesn't have to be old to achieve that.

  For example, you're visiting the page which is fake bank website, or can be real bank (with some forum where somebody uploaded fake JPEG via [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)). So to implement XSS Keylogger, you just need `document.onkeypress` + AJAX calls. See: [XSS Keylogger](http://wiremask.eu/xss-keylogger/)

  Also check: [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)
- loading JPEG which is SVG

  Sometimes when you load media file and web-browser recognise it as different image, it fallback to the format which was recognised. And what you can do in SVG files, you can include html and JavaScript into it (if your web-browser allows that), see: [Create a table in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6987005/55075) (and [another one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263841/191655)).

Comment: Nicely covered and sourced. Certainly a good argument for sand-boxing the browser.

Answer (score 4):

*Normally* it wouldn't be possible. JPEG files contain just compressed image data; they don't really contain any parts which would be run as program code, and certainly not something that would give such broad access to the system.

However, programs have bugs. More specifically, some of the various libraries used for decompressing JPEG data *may* have bugs which allow the program to be tricked into running parts of the data as program code, often using a [buffer overflow](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/08/how-security-flaws-work-the-buffer-overflow/) or similar bug.

---

(Also, some *other* image formats are poorly designed *do* contain runnable code by design... two of the better-known examples are [WMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile_vulnerability) and PDF.)

Comment: Hmm. [Code injection – a simple PHP virus carried in a JPEG image](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/13/php-code-injection-a-simple-virus-written-in-php-and-carried-in-a-jpeg-image/) - a real exploit embedded in an image ...

Answer (score 2):

This is unlikely.

It is more likely, that this is an executable that is named such as: `image1.jpg.exe`. If extensions are hidden, you will see `Image1.jpg`.

The program has the icon of a jpg image, and by starting the program it extracts an embedded image to the temp folder and starts it to simulate the image being opened and not raise suspicions. The program then installs the keylogger.

But this is not an image with embedded keylogger. Its a program pretending to be an image with an embedded keylogger, trying to trick the person into opening the image, the same way spyware is being made to trick the user to open it and install itself.

Comment: Hmm. [Code injection – a simple PHP virus carried in a JPEG image](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/13/php-code-injection-a-simple-virus-written-in-php-and-carried-in-a-jpeg-image/) - a real exploit embedded in an image ...

Comment: Never say "This is not possible" when it comes to computers ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill : good point. it would need exploits and thus not really work in most programs, but that makes it unlikely rather than impossible. post edited. :)

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you display some sort of file, you read it and process the content so that it can be displayed correctly (for example read the image data and calculate each pixel). Because an image file is totally static and the data it contains is always similar, it is extremely unlikely that the data which the image viewer looks for and processes (like color information in certain areas) can be executed as malicious code.

Comment: Hmm. [Code injection – a simple PHP virus carried in a JPEG image](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/13/php-code-injection-a-simple-virus-written-in-php-and-carried-in-a-jpeg-image/) - a real exploit embedded in an image ...